# PHP giving a trailing "=" on each line after reading from stdin

Tags: php, stdin, word-wrap, fread, trailing

The contents of stdin is getting corrupted with word wrapping and trailing "=" throughout which obviously breaks the URL that I need to post.

I need to extract a URL/link from an email then post the URL. So, I'm piping my email to a php script in cpanel using a standard code snip I've seen all over the internet:

```
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = ""; // This will be the variable holding the data.
while (!feof($fd)) { $email .= trim(fread($fd, 1024)); }
fclose($fd);
```

Then dumping the contents of the email to a file "pipemail.txt" for now to inspect it and make sure it's all working properly.

```
$fdw = fopen("pipemail.txt", "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);
```

The output is looking like this:

```
...
<table style=3D"width:100%" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0=
"><tbody><tr><td><table style=3D"background-color:#ffffff;color:#3c445a;fon=
t-family:arial;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;width:100%" cellpadding=3D"0=
" cellspacing=3D"0">
...
```

I have been working on this for over a day now and I'm completely stumped. I've tried trimming the trailing "=" from incoming lines and it does not give me the expected result. Instead it seems to remove random "=" from seemingly random locations in the content. I am guessing that it is not random but it only seems so because it's not what I expect. It's probably only removing it if it happens to be the last character of the 1024 k/char line but if that is true then where else is the wordwrapping coming from? I don't know enough about how this works to trouble shoot this myself.

Why is it wrapping? Where are the "=" coming from? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the `=` characters aren't in the original text? `=` at the end of the line is used in the `quoted-printable` format that's often used for email.

Comment: take a look at the raw source of the email and I'll bet you'll see those characters are already there.

Comment: Similarly, `=3D` is how the `=` is represented in quoted-printable.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was missing. Thank you @Barmar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emails are commonly encoded in the quoted printable format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

You can decode it using `quoted_printable_decode()` - this is done automatically by your email client, which is why it looks like php is adding those character.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php

Comment: That was it. Thank yuu @sam-dufel.

Comment: Amazingly have had difficulty finding this information for quite some time, exactly what I needed. This should have more upvotes and should be higher in google results

Answer (score 0):

> from an email

and

> trailing “=” on each line

means that the email is probably quoted-printable encoded. You need to parse the message properly and run the body part through [`quoted_printable_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php).

There are `Content-Type` headers that will tell you what kind of encoding is used, and probably MIME parts and boundaries that you'll need to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) format, use `quoted_printable_decode` to decode it:

```
$email = quoted_printable_decode(file_get_contents("php:://stdin"));
```